# Why “super” for supersynchronous orbits? Why not “trans”?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, terminology, supersynchronous

I was just getting used to “cis” and “trans” for orbits inside and outside the Lunar orbit. “Trans” is a Latin word root meaning “across, beyond, or through”(Meriam Webster).

“Trans” seems like a better choice than “super” (also Latin) meaning “over, above” (Meriam Webster). The key here is whether the object crossed the defining line. Mars may be a “supralunar” body, but it is certainly not “translunar”. A journey to Mars is translunar, but not Mars itself.

On the other hand, a satellite transferred to GSO may have used a “transynchronous” trajectory. But it was only supersynchronous for a short part of its journey.

It’s hard enough to use “cis” and “trans” correctly here on Earth without causing confusion in the Heavens.

Comment: I always read the term as "supersynchronous" = "more than synchronous" = "longer period than synchronous", not as "translunar" = "behind the moon".  So, at least for me, it makes sense to have "supersynchronous" and (not actually used) something like "trans-geo-stationary". One is motion-wise, one is position-wise.

Answer (score 2):

I know (from personal experience) that the term and concept "supersynchronous" was being used back in the 1980s, at least. That was long, long before anybody started talking about cis-lunar space and the like. Sometimes the terminology isn't consistent, but I guess that's OK as long as we all understand what each other is saying.

Comment: The term "cislunar" was used during Apollo.  "The Apollo 12 crew now making preparations for cislunar navigation tasks. " Apollo 12 Flight Journal https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap12fj/21day8_cislunar_nav.html

Comment: @John McCarthy ---  Neologisms are coming at us fast and furious. Elon seams to think everything big is "giga". At least "trans" and "supra" are reasonably synonymous with "beyond".

Answer (score 1):

To back up [@John McCarthy's answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57758/12102) I just happened to run across the following passage from [Military Communications - 1968: Hearings Before a Subcommittee of the Committee on Government Operations, House of Representatives](https://books.google.com/books?id=ggMCWUYOKesC&pg=PA47&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=subsynchronous&f=false) which while it doesn't contain "supersynchronous" it does contain "subsynchronous" in reference to [LES-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln_Experimental_Satellite) `1967-066E` which [according to n2yo.com/satellite/?s=2866](https://www.n2yo.com/satellite/?s=2866) has a semimajor axis of 39,779 km and a period of 21.93 hours and a mean motion of 1.0943 orbits per day.

> As you know, the MIT-Lincoln Laboratory experimental ultra-high-frequency satellite (LES-5) **was successfully launched last July into a subsynchronous equatorial orbit.** Since that time, joint test operations have been conducted by the military departments using "off-the-shelf" terminals. In March of this year, the satellite experienced some degradation due to a transistor failure in a preamplifier...

[image: LES-5 position from https://www.n2yo.com/satellite/?s=2866]

Here's [LES-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LES-1) `1965-008C` for reference from [Lincoln_Laboratory_LES-1_1965](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lincoln_Laboratory_LES-1_1965.jpg)

[image: Lincoln Laboratory launched LES-1 in 1965 originally from NASA]